# How to do inversion of control on CompositeCommand?

Tags: c#, mvvm, inversion-of-control, prism

I have the following ViewModel where I instantiate the CompositeCommand inside the constructor:

```
 public class ViewImportPreviewViewModel:BindableBase
    {
        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;  //event aggregator to enable Studio button in different ViewModel

        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager; //region manager for navigation to the main menu

        public CompositeCommand FinalizeImportClick{get;set;}//composite command to register multiple command for finalize import button click


        public ViewImportPreviewViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) //constructor
        {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;

            FinalizeImportClick = new CompositeCommand();
            FinalizeImportClick.RegisterCommand(new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateToMain)); //register a delegate command for finalize import button click


        }


        //subscriber method to the firs delegate command registered with finalize button click
        private void NavigateToMain(string argument) 
        {
            //it enables the studio button after import and sends it to the main menu view XAML
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<ButtonEnableEvent>().Publish("ImportDone");

            //it navigates to the main menu after import
            regionManager.RequestNavigate("ScreenNavigationRegion", argument); 

            //publish an event for the main buttons viewmodel and then over there try to fade in main buttons
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<FadeinButtonsEvent>().Publish("ImportDone");
        }


    }
```

Now I want to do the inversion of control, and instantiate the CompositeCommand outside the class and then inject it through Unity Container like this:

```
 public class ViewImportPreviewViewModel:BindableBase
    {
        private IEventAggregator eventAggregator;  //event aggregator to enable Studio button in different ViewModel

        private readonly IRegionManager regionManager; //region manager for navigation to the main menu

        public CompositeCommand finalizeImportClick;//composite command to register multiple command for finalize import button click


        public ViewImportPreviewViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, CompositeCommand finalizeImportClick) //constructor
        {
            this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
            this.regionManager = regionManager;

            this.finalizeImportClick = finalizeImportClick;
            finalizeImportClick.RegisterCommand(new DelegateCommand<string>(NavigateToMain)); //register a delegate command for finalize import button click


        }


        //subscriber method to the firs delegate command registered with finalize button click
        private void NavigateToMain(string argument) 
        {
            //it enables the studio button after import and sends it to the main menu view XAML
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<ButtonEnableEvent>().Publish("ImportDone");

            //it navigates to the main menu after import
            regionManager.RequestNavigate("ScreenNavigationRegion", argument); 

            //publish an event for the main buttons viewmodel and then over there try to fade in main buttons
            eventAggregator.GetEvent<FadeinButtonsEvent>().Publish("ImportDone");
        }


    }
```

and then on module initialization, I do this:

```
  CompositeCommand myCommand = new CompositeCommand();
  container.RegisterInstance<CompositeCommand>(myCommand);
```

I don't get any errors, but `NavigateToMain(string argument)` does not get called, although the command gets registered.

I tried to register type instead, but CompositeCommand inherits ICommand interface which doesn't contain a definition for `RegisterCommand` method.

Comment: My first question is, why would you want do this in the first place? Is it for unit testing? I can't see any other reason why you'd want to initialize it outside the viewmodel. Also your attempt is pretty dangerous one, as the `CompositeCommand` now is singleton and will be passed in every of your views ever created, they register and by this the composite command holds a reference to your viewmodel. if you don't unsubscribe the event at some time, the viewmodel will never be garbage collected, because `CompositeCommand` now has a lifetime thats equal to the one of your application

Comment: To be honest, I do not have any particular reason for doing this. I was just trying to follow the SOLID principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is very common that CompositeCommands are singletons/static because multiple loosely coupled modules will register for the same CompositeCommand.  This is standard, and expected.

Of course you want to do this to keep your ViewModel testable.  You want your dependencies known via the ctor.  You don't want to make calls to static methods in your VM.

What you want to do is create a custom interface like IApplicationCommands, and provide properties for each CompositeCommand you want to expose, then make sure to register that interface with your container.  I would also recommend providing a static version so that you can data bind buttons to the compositeCommands without having to reference a binding, which is really nice.

So maybe something like this:

```
    //Create an interface to abstract away the implementation of the static GlobalCommands class
public interface IGlobalCommands
{
    CompositeCommand SaveAllCommand { get; }
}

public static class GlobalCommands
{
    public static CompositeCommand SaveAllCommand = new CompositeCommand();
}

//Create a facade around the static GlobalCommands class
public class GloablCommandsFacade : IGlobalCommands
{
    public CompositeCommand SaveAllCommand
    {
        get { return GlobalCommands.SaveAllCommand; }
    }
}
```

And register like this:

```
//register our global commands facade with the container as the IGlobalCommands interface so that we can ask for this service in our VM constructors
        // and remove the call to a static class in our VM.  This keeps us testable.
        Container.RegisterType<IGlobalCommands, GloablCommandsFacade>();
```